# Calculate DateTimeField() via variables

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-datetime

I am new to python and can't wrap my head around a solution for my simple issue for days now.

I have an *Event* model which should allow the user to book a **timeslot**, **room** and **event type** that will be shown in a timetable.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    get_date = models.DateTimeField()      # set via form, has year and day
    start_time_choices = [('1', '07:30'), ('2', '07:45'), ('3', '08:00'), ('4', '08:15'), ('5', '08:30')]
    timeslots = models.TimeField(
        choices=start_time_choices,
        "%H:%M",
        default='1',
        null=True)
    room_choices = [('1', 'Room 1'), ('2', 'Room 2'), ('3', 'Room 3'), ('4', 'Room 4'), ('5', 'Room 5')]
    room = models.CharField(
        choices=room_choices,
        max_length=1,
        default='1',
        null=True)
    event_choices = [('1', 'Event A'), ('2', 'Event B')]      # A is 15min long, B is 30min long
    events= models.CharField(
        choices=event_choices,
        max_length=1,
        default='1',
        null=True)
```

Now I want to calculate the start_time and end_time for this event which is used for the calendar view

- Where do I put the following calculation? Directly in models.py?
- How do I handle proper date calculation?

```
# this is not a real code

    @property
    def date_calc(self):
        start_date = get_date + timeslots      # Year & Day + Hour & Min

        if events == "Event A":
          end_date = start_date + "00:15"
        else:
          end_date = end_date + "00:30"

        return start_time, end_time
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I put the following calculation? Directly in models.py?

You can add it to your `models.py`, but as that module grows, you might want to create a `models` folder with separate modules.

> How do I handle proper date calculation?

You can overwrite

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

And do the calculation there. Basically it calculates start_time and end_time before the actual save and then saves them.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    start_date = get_date + timeslots      # Year & Day + Hour & Min

    if events == "Event A":
      end_date = start_date + "00:15"
    else:
      end_date = end_date + "00:30"

    super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: alright thanks!

one more thing regarding the handling of time: should i rather create the start_date from strings and parse that or is a "calculation" (working with timefields) recommended?

Comment: if possible to avoid conversions, do that

Comment: ok, going to try it like this:
- start_date= get_date.replace(hour=7, minutes=30)

again, thanks for your time